# Error message in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

Can any one tell me what shall I do when `Eclipse` shows this message:

```
[2012-02-28 10:57:34 - LMP] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

Actually it was shown when I took a project from anther laptop then I added it to my workspace then I imported it to my eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using java 1.7 when 1.6 or 1.5 required.

Answer (score 2):

`Project > Properties > Java Compiler`

Set compiler compliance level to 1.5 or 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Java 7 on your project, but the VM on Android only supports Java 5~6.

Just have to configure eclipse to use Java 6 compliance level (: